How to use UICollectionView compostional layout to display a imageviews based on different ratio?
I have a NSCollectionLayoutItem which contains a UIImageView , and I wanna this NSCollectionLayoutItem fill the device horizontal fully. and I set both the item and group 's heightDimension to estimatedDimension.
And because the UIImageView's content is downloaded from HTTP request. so I set a placehold image to this imageview , and the placeholder image 's height is 258.
But after the image download request complete . the NSCollectionLayoutItem will display at the height 258 still ,which is the placehold image's height . and the image downloaded may got a different ratio . but it seems no way to change the height after downloading complete.
Is there any way to display image content based on it's content 's aspect ratio using UICollectionView compostional layout
the layout code :
- (NSCollectionLayoutSection*)bulletinSection
{
    
    NSCollectionLayoutSize* itemSize = [NSCollectionLayoutSize sizeWithWidthDimension:[NSCollectionLayoutDimension fractionalWidthDimension:1] heightDimension:[NSCollectionLayoutDimension estimatedDimension:100]];
    NSCollectionLayoutItem* item = [NSCollectionLayoutItem itemWithLayoutSize:itemSize];
    
    NSCollectionLayoutSize* groupSize = [NSCollectionLayoutSize sizeWithWidthDimension:[NSCollectionLayoutDimension fractionalWidthDimension:1] heightDimension:[NSCollectionLayoutDimension estimatedDimension:100]];
    NSCollectionLayoutGroup* group = [NSCollectionLayoutGroup horizontalGroupWithLayoutSize:groupSize subitems:@[item]];
    
    NSCollectionLayoutSection* section = [NSCollectionLayoutSection sectionWithGroup:group];
    return section;
}

the cell configuaration code :
    UICollectionViewCellRegistration* bulletinCellRegistration = [UICollectionViewCellRegistration registrationWithCellNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"MeBulletinCell" bundle:nil] configurationHandler:^(__kindof UICollectionViewCell * _Nonnull cell, NSIndexPath * _Nonnull indexPath, id  _Nonnull item) {
        MeBulletinCell* bulletinCell = (MeBulletinCell*)cell;

        if ([weakSelf.bulletinDic isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]])
        {
            bulletinCell.bulletinInfo = weakSelf.bulletinDic;
        }
    }];

- (void)setBulletinInfo:(NSDictionary *)bulletinInfo
{
    _bulletinInfo = bulletinInfo;

    [self.bulletinImageView km_setImageWithUrl:bulletinInfo[@"image_url"] placeholder:[UIImage imageNamed:@"NewHomeDefault43"]];
}


Would you post some code, how you made compositional collection view?

@Shivbaba'sson thanks I have post the related code

Hi, can you calculate the downloaded image's aspect ratio. Your width is fixed. And height you can calculate from aspect ratio. Width/aspect ratio. That estimated height you can pass     NSCollectionLayoutSize* itemSize = [NSCollectionLayoutSize sizeWithWidthDimension:[NSCollectionLayoutDimension fractionalWidthDimension:1] heightDimension:[NSCollectionLayoutDimension estimatedDimension:100]]; instead of 100.

So, when you reload the section, after image downloaded, you might get new item height.

@Shivbaba'sson but the reload action will reload the image downloading , and the image downloading will reload the section again , this will cause a infinite loop~

Try take array of ids, if you have some from your data, km_setImageWithUrl this function should have closure or completion, when your image loads add that id in array. And reload row for item for collection view method. Next time you can check that id contains in array if not then only load image from km_setImageWithUrl like this.

Yes, you can display images based on their content's aspect ratio using UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout. Set the item's aspect ratio in the layout definition, and use content mode properties of the UIImageView to adjust how the downloaded image is displayed, such as UIView.ContentMode.scaleAspectFill.

but the item's aspect ratio is unkown at first, and after the image download , if I observe the image downloading and reload the item , this reload will download the image again and cause a infinite loop
