How to use UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout to render a remote image properly in UIKit
I want to display a NSCollectionLayoutItem( contains a image from remote and its aspect ratio is unkown) occupy the device screen horizontally , and still get the correct aspect ratio in Vertical .
So I use the NSCollectionLayoutDimension.estimated(50) points  for height . but after the image is downloaded , the height is still 50 ,which is not enough for display the image .
How to make the layout automatically fit the image's content.
the image link is here : [image src] (https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png)
image content is :

and the running result will be like this

the UICollectionView configuration code :
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    enum Section {
        case main
    }
    
    @IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!
    var dataSource: UICollectionViewDiffableDataSource<Section, Int>! = nil
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        self.configDataSource()
        self.configLayout()
    }

    
    func configDataSource() {
        let imageCellReg = UICollectionView.CellRegistration<ImageCell,Int>(cellNib: UINib(nibName: "ImageCell", bundle: nil)) { cell, indexPath, itemIdentifier in
            
        }
        self.dataSource = UICollectionViewDiffableDataSource<Section, Int>(collectionView: self.collectionView, cellProvider: { collectionView, indexPath, itemIdentifier in
            return self.collectionView.dequeueConfiguredReusableCell(using: imageCellReg, for: indexPath, item: itemIdentifier)
        })
        
        var snapshot = NSDiffableDataSourceSnapshot<Section, Int>()
        snapshot.appendSections([.main])
        snapshot.appendItems(Array(0..<2))
        dataSource.apply(snapshot, animatingDifferences: false)

    }
    
    func configLayout(){
        let itemSize = NSCollectionLayoutSize(widthDimension: .fractionalWidth(1.0),
                                             heightDimension: .fractionalHeight(1.0))
        let item = NSCollectionLayoutItem(layoutSize: itemSize)

        let groupSize = NSCollectionLayoutSize(widthDimension: .fractionalWidth(1.0),
                                               heightDimension:.estimated(50))
        let group = NSCollectionLayoutGroup.horizontal(layoutSize:groupSize, subitems: [item])
        let spacing = CGFloat(10)
        group.interItemSpacing = .fixed(spacing)

        let section = NSCollectionLayoutSection(group: group)
        section.interGroupSpacing = spacing
        section.contentInsets = NSDirectionalEdgeInsets(top: 0, leading: 10, bottom: 0, trailing: 10)

        let layout = UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout(section: section)
        self.collectionView.collectionViewLayout = layout
    }

}

And the cell code:
import UIKit
import SDWebImage

class ImageCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    @IBOutlet weak var imageContentView: UIImageView!
    
    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
        imageContentView.sd_setImage(with: URL(string: "https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png"))
    }

}


Is this different than your previous question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78370684/how-to-use-uicollectionview-compostional-layout-to-display-a-imageviews-based-on

@DonMag , it's the more exactly problem of the previous quesiton

Best not to post as a new question - better to continue discussion with people who have responded already. I'd suggest you head over to your favorite search engine and search for SDWebImage set uicollectionviewcell height after download ... lots of discussions and examples already exist.

@DonMag , it has nothing to do with SDWebImage , In fact the problem is you can't set the correct height for cell  if you don't know the exactly aspect ratio  first.And if you reset the cell after downloading with the aspect ratio just get , In most situations,it 's  means to  reload the the image again . and cause the infinite loop ,(maybe there is some ways you can do  to avoid this loop), but I think there should be some good practice for this scenario.

@DonMag,maybe you can write a demo to display google icon image from remote with uicollectionviewcompositionallayout ,and you'll know what I am confuseing~

@ximmyxiao i am getting this kind of result https://ibb.co/wpNqrQs

same code is used ? is it ok ?

@Shivbaba'sson thanks  , DonMan‘s code is very useful for me ~

Very quick example...
Design your cell like this:

We've given the image view a Height constraint -- which will be updated when the image has been downloaded.
The cell class is as simple as this:
class ImageCell: UICollectionViewCell {

    @IBOutlet var imageContentView: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet var imgHeight: NSLayoutConstraint!
    
}

Using SDWebImage, we'll implement a completion block, where we'll calculate the aspect-ratio height for the downloaded image, which we'll use to set the imgHeight.constant. We then call collectionView.collectionViewLayout.invalidateLayout() to tell the controller to re-layout the cells:
cell.imageContentView.sd_setImage (
    with: URL(string: urlStr),
    placeholderImage: UIImage(named: "somePlaceholder"),
    options: SDWebImageOptions(rawValue: 0),
    completed: { [weak self] image, error, cacheType, imageURL in
        guard let self = self,
              let img = image
        else { return }
        
        // calculate proportional height
        let iw = cell.imageContentView.frame.width
        let ih = (img.size.height / img.size.width) * iw
        
        // update the height contraint in the cell
        cell.imgHeight.constant = ih
        
        // tell the collection view to re-layout the cells
        self.collectionView.collectionViewLayout.invalidateLayout()
    }
)

        

Here is a complete example project: https://github.com/DonMag/SDWebCV

Thanks , seems the invalidateLayout will not  reload the cell ,so the infinite loop will not exist , I use to call reloadData/Item in the completion block . very useful to learned that~!

I see the height constraint for the cell added in the project , Is this constraint has to be exist ? or the Self-Sizing  can do the same thing without this height constraint ?

@ximmyxiao - you have to do something to tell the collection view how tall to make the cell. This is one approach. You haven't provided any details related to anything else you might be wanting to do with your UI ... you could use a custom layout instead of a CompositionalLayout, but I have no idea what your end goal is.

In fact , I am  refactoring a page from flutter to iOS native code , and I found that the List+Image will work well for any-size image without those resetting height works. So I wanna know is it possible to do the same in native iOS code . because I thought the Self-Sizing mechanism of iOS may do the same as flutter ,and I don't need to set the height manually . but it seems I am wrong @DonMag

@ximmyxiao - I don't know anything about Flutter or its UI components. In iOS, a UIImageView can be set to .scaleToFill, .scaleAspectFit, .scaleAspectFill (and some less common modes) to control how the image is sized inside the view frame, but it doesn't have "change the view frame to match the image". You could subclass UIImageView to get that functionality, but... is there a reason you don't want to use the constraint method I gave you?

Thanks @DonMag , because in most times ,you don't have to set a height constraint for cell , the Self-Sizing mechanism of UIKit will set the correct height for the cell. (e.g  a cell has only a label). I think this kind of 'cell-without-height-constraint 's layout is more simple to using than the 'cell-has-to-set-height-constraint's layout. But as you say: the image itself  doesn't have "change the view frame to match the image". So ,it seems if I want to make a cell-without-height-constraint of image I have to subclass UIImageView and overwrite it's intrinsicContentSize

@ximmyxiao - yes, if you want a UI component to have different properties/behaviors than its default, you have to subclass it. In the code you posted, you are already subclassing UIViewController and UICollectionViewCell ... so subclassing UIImageView would be just another step to get your desired results.
